Bitbucket pipeline fails for grep command in exclude hidden directory
I have the following command to run:
grep -r -n --exclude-dir='.test' ERROR . >> errors.txt
This works fine on the terminal but when I run this on bitbucket pipeline via yml file, it fails with the error:
grep: unrecognized option: exclude-dir=.test
Could someone please help figure out the correct syntax?
Thanks
I have tried
grep -r -n --exclude-dir='.test' ERROR . >> errors.txt

and
grep -r -n --exclude-dir=.test ERROR . >> errors.txt

Docker: alpine android
github.com/alvr/alpine-android

The reason this doesn't work is that alpine images need additional grep upgrade for grep to work properly.
The following works:
script:
    - apk add --no-cache --upgrade grep
    - grep -r -n --exclude-dir='.test' ERROR . >> errors.txt


Alpine images feature different implementations for usual shell tooling. Most of them do not accept long (double dash) options, and some of them feature only a subset of all the options accepted by the regular tooling shipped in non-alpine Linux distributions.
Unless you are using a pipeline runner with a severe hardware disk constraint, I'd suggest you avoid alpine-flavored images for your steps.
